# How to generate Natspec docs using version 0.6.x of the Solidity compiler

Tags: solc, compilation, solidity-0.6.x, docker, natspec

I'm trying to run  `solc --userdoc --devdoc myContract.sol` to generate [natspec](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/natspec-format.html). However, the compiler complains that the contract has a different pragma-version. In fact the contract pragma is at `^0.6.0` and I also use an external contract interface `@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol`.

When I install `solc` on my ubuntu machine with `sudo snap install solc` it installs some (the wrong) version and I don't see how I can change the install version or switch between versions.

I pip-installed the python package `https://github.com/crytic/solc-select` which promised to do the job. But when I run `solc --version` I still have the incompatible version, on which my contract wont compile.

When I use the docker images

```bash
sudo docker run -v $HOME/myProject/contracts:/contracts ethereum/solc:0.6.12 -o /contracts/output --abi --bin /contracts/myContract.sol
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
```

This issue is also reported [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28575/source-filename-not-found-file-outside-of-allowed-directories-solidity-so), but this seems like a rabbit hole that I shouldn't want to get into.

Comment: `solc` accept list of redirect paths, check this option out

Comment: just download all the versions of `solc` you need from `Releases` section of Github

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked the instruction on the [official solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/installing-solidity.html#docker) page worked with solc and docker.

For example to compile `/ethereum/test.sol` and leave the outputs at `/ethereum/build`.

```
docker run -v /ethereum:/sources ethereum/solc:0.5.16 --abi --bin /sources/test.sol -o /sources/build
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get any version of the compiler for any supported platform from [solc-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/). The compiler is a single statically compiled binary so there's really not much point in running it via Docker unless you just really like that as a way to easily download it. The binary is the only file inside the docker image anyway.

To download and run 0.6.x:

```bash
curl -OL https://binaries.soliditylang.org/linux-amd64/solc-linux-amd64-v0.6.12+commit.27d51765
chmod +x solc-linux-amd64-v0.6.12+commit.27d51765
./solc-linux-amd64-v0.6.12+commit.27d51765 --userdoc --devdoc myContract.sol
```

If `myContract.sol` contains `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol"`, you also need to make sure that the compiler can find that file. In 0.8.8+ you can install chainlink via npm and simply add `--include-path node_modules/` to the `solc` command. That option was not available on 0.6.x and the workaround is to create a symlink to it inside your project directory

```bash
ln -s node_modules/@chainlink/ @chainlink
```

or, alternatively, use [import remapping](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/path-resolution.html#import-remapping) (note however that remapping affects contract metadata):

```bash
./solc-linux-amd64-v0.6.12+commit.27d51765 @chainlink/=node_modules/@chainlink/ --userdoc --devdoc myContract.sol
```

> When I install `solc` on my ubuntu machine with `sudo snap install solc` it installs some (the wrong) version and I don't see how I can change the install version or switch between versions.

The snap package is maintained by the community on the best-effort basis and is unfortunately out of date right now ([#11940](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11940)). I'd really recommend to use the static binary instead.

> When I use the docker images `sudo docker run -v $HOME/myProject/contracts:/contracts ethereum/solc:0.6.12 -o /contracts/output --abi --bin /contracts/myContract.sol` I get the error: `Error: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.`.

The compiler will refuse to import files from outside of your project directory unless you specifically tell it it's fine. You can do this using `--allow-paths` option. This should contain the directory where you installed chainlink.

Note that, if you're using solc from Docker, it should be a directory in container's filesystem rather than in your local filesystem. The fact that there are two parallel filesystems connected via Docker volumes is often confusing to users which is why, again, I'd recommend a static binary instead - it will make dealing with paths much more straightforward.